# How to add custom css to swagger UI in Golang?

Tags: go, swagger, swagger-ui, go-fiber

I'm working on a **Golang** project at the moment. As a framework, I use **go-fibre**. To implement swagger documentation, I utilize **swaggo/swag** and **fibre-swagger**. I need to modify my swagger output page (eg: Font size should be increased, colour should be changed, the logo should be removed. etc..). Therefore, in Golang, how do I apply custom CSS for Swagger?
Thanks.

Comment: I think there is no role for Go to add custom CSS. you need to check with the swagger side or in the swagger folder